# CORS Intermittently Failing - Not Loading Resources

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

I am intermittently getting this error for assets on a site we've just developed:

Failed to load https://pod-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/client-logos/1522890659604509292c41c4c7b07f778b5254249d.svg: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.pereiraodell.com' is therefore not allowed access.

19/20 times the site loads correctly. Any thoughts on what the cause could be? We were thinking that the CORS headers hadn't properly propagated across S3 servers, but it's been a few weeks now.

Comment: Throws an error for me every time I access the URL. What are your CORS configurations?

Comment: @Pete Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I'm experiencing intermittent CORS failures with my own app. Works like a charm most of the time, then just fails  out of nowhere and I'm going out of my mind trying to debug the issue.